# Npgsql with netcoreapp2.0 on AWS Lambda is unable to connect (has timeout) - how can I resolve?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, f#, aws-lambda, npgsql

I'm trying to deploy a netcoreapp2.0 application to AWS Lambda that connects to Postgres on RDS.  The following code fails:

```
    let testConn = "Host=hostNameHere;Username=userNameHere;Password=passwordHere;Database=postgres";
    let conn = new NpgsqlConnection(testConn)
    try
        printfn "Trying to open a connection"
        conn.Open()
    with ex ->
        printfn "Exception trying to open conn:\n%O" ex
```

I get the following stack trace:

```
System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Connect(NpgsqlTimeout timeout)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<RawOpen>d__153.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<Open>d__149.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.<AllocateLong>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<<Open>g__OpenLong|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open()
at Masse.Common.SQL.query[T](String connectString, SqlQuery q) in /home/nat/Projects/shopmasse-backend/fsharp/src/Masse.Common/Sql.fs:line 40
```

Does anyone know why this might fail with deployed to AWS lambda, but work locally on my machine?

Here are some GitHub issues that may provide additional context:

- https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/issues/288
- https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/1984

Some additional details:
- DB Engine: PostgreSQL 9.6.6 
- Npgsql version: 4.0
- .NET version: netcoreapp2.0

Please let me know if I can provide any additional information.  Thank you!

Comment: This has probably nothing to do with Npgsql. I would say that you've omitted to specify an inbound rule in the RDS instance security group ?

Comment: @OlivierMATROT Thanks for chiming in.  The RDS instance is publicly accessible, and I can access it from my computer using Datagrip without issue.  Doesn't that indicate that it is able to receive inbound connections?

Comment: It depends. What are the inbound rules of the security group of your RDS instance ? Probably you're own IP is whitelisted in there. You have to allow the security group associated with your lambda too.

Comment: Holy crap I think you're right.  My IP is whitelisted!!  I guess that got set up automatically.  Just added another inbound IP rule to the list, we'll see if it fixes things.

Comment: yes that got set automatically when you initiated the instance :)

Comment: @OlivierMATROT That solve the issue, woohoo!  Feel free to leave an answer below, I'll tag it as having solved the issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A connection timeout usually indicates a firewall problem.

Your connection request is blocked by the security group of your RDS instance.

When you've created the instance, the IP of the computer running the AWS console is automatically whitelisted.

Any other external or internal resource accessing PostgreSQL must be whitelisted as well.

I hope you'll enjoy AWS RDS running PostgreSQL, I find it awesome.